# What's wrong with the code below in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I had an interview and I had this question, but I failed. Can someone point what is wrong in here?

So, at the company I was presented to this code and asked to identify as many problems as I can with the code below:

File T1.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void (^TestClassCallback)();

// Person is a subclass of NSManagedObject
@class Person;

@interface T1 : NSObject
- (void)doWorkWithPerson:(Person*)aPerson callback:(TestClassCallback)aCallback;
@end
```

File T1.m

```
#import "T1.h"
#import "Person.h"
#import "ProgressBar.h"

@implementation T1

static TestClassCallback savedCallback;

- (void)doWorkWithPerson:(Person*)aPerson callback:(TestClassCallback)aCallback {
      savedCallback = aCallback;
      [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(doVeryLongTask1:) withObject:aPerson];
}

- (void)doVeryLongTask1:(Person*)aPerson {
      double p = 0.0;
      // Do some actions.
      // ...
      // ...
      [[ProgressBar instance] update:p];
      // Do more actions.
      // ...
      // ...
      [[ProgressBar instance] update:p];
      // Do final actions.
      (savedCallback)();
}

@end
```

As far as I can think, the problem with the callback and sending to a background, plus updating the Progress Bar.

Comment: Why do you make `savedCallback` as static? Did you update `ProgressBar` on main queue? Your naming convention is not clear enough.

Comment: Everything about that is either archaic or wrong.  If that is literally what they gave you, “toss it out and follow modern patterns” would be a correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it is not my code, I had this code and I had to find out what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1):

Main problem I see is that if this gets called again before the original invocation has completed, you'll overwrite `savedCallback` and the original invocation's callback will never be called (and the second one will be called twice).

In 2018, I'd forego the rather archaic selector-based approach to run tasks in the background, and go with blocks-based GCD instead. So, something like this:

```
- (void)doWorkWithPerson:(Person*)aPerson callback:(TestClassCallback)aCallback {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self doVeryLongTask1:aPerson];
        aCallback();
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `aCallback` be called after `doVeryLongTask1:`  if `doVeryLongTask1:` does some asynchronous jobs?

Comment: @trungduc Just going with the example given, in which `doVeryLongTask1:` is written as a synchronous method. If `doVeryLongTask1:` is async, then you should obviously pass it the callback and have it fire after all the tasks are completed.

Comment: Of course we will need a callback here. He updates `ProgressBar` inside `doVeryLongTask1:` so I'm pretty sure that it's async. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @trungduc Since there's no reason for the worker to have to wait for the UI before continuing, there's no reason to assume that the `ProgressBar` class isn't using `dispatch_async` to the main queue to update the UI. No reason that would need to make the method async.

Comment: Adding these point:
- it wil crash if callback is nil.
- the completion is in a separate thread then the call.
- Person is not thread safe (NSManagedObject).